# How to add multiple child records to parent list in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

My classes are like this:

```
public class ParentModel
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
   public string ParentName { get; set; }
   public List<ChildModel> ChildModel { get; set; }
}

public class ChildModel
{
   public int ParentID { get; set; }
   public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
```

And I am using it like this.

```
List<ParentModel> parentModel = new List<ParentModel>();
using(MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
{
   foreach(Parent parent in db.Parents.Where(some_condition_here))
   {
      parentModel.Add (
         new ParentModel {
            ID = parent.ID,
            ParentName = parent.ParentName
         }
      );
   }
}
```

Problem is I don't know how to add child records to each parent record. Can't seem to construct syntax for it. How can I include child records with each parent record?

Comment: If your table has the self-join relationship to make the parent-child relationship, you need the [`.Include()` to load the related entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data).

Comment: Yes my table has self join baesd on ID in parent table, and parentID in child table but I am unable to write correct syntax to get child records.

Comment: You haven't actually tried, based on what you posted. Did you follow the link provided in the first comment? Did you try to implement it? If not, why not? What do you not understand? If so, what happened? If it worked, post an answer. If it didn't, update your question and show us what you did and tell us what happened. Don't just sit on your hands and wait for someone to provide a turnkey solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have FK relation to child entities, which I will just call `ChildEntities` here, so just do

```
var parents = db.Parents
    .Where(some_condition_here)
    .Include(x => x.ChildEntities)
    .ToArray();
```

and then

```
foreach (var parent in parents)
{
    parentModel.Add(new ParentModel 
    {
        ID = parent.ID,
        ParentName = parent.ParentName,
        ChildModel = parent.ChildEntities
            .Select(x => new ChildModel 
            { 
                ParentId = parent.Id, 
                ChildName = x.Name,
            })
            .ToArray(),
    });
}
```

Comment: Typo error, missing "r" for `.ToArray()`.